# Global Variable Undefined? Can't get label to display global variable from function

Tags: python, tkinter

This is a little program I am making to learn Python which is a NPC Trait Generator that generates random words from a text file.

My random generator works, but I can't get it to display properly in the label. I currently have pertrait set to global but it doesn't seem to pick up the variable to display in the label? I tried setting up StringVar but I couldn't seem to get that to work properly either.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font


# Random Personality generation from text list
def gen():
    global pertrait
    pertrait = print(random.choice(open(
        'F:\\Desktop\\python\\RandomGenerator py\\CharTraitList.txt').read(
        ).split()).strip())


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("NPC Trait Generator")
root.geometry("500x200")
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

# define font
fontStyle = font.Font(family='Courier', size=44, weight='bold')

# background image variable and import
paper = tk.PhotoImage(
    file='F:\\Desktop\\python\\RandomGenerator py\\papbckgrd.png')

butQuit = tk.Button(frame,
                    text="Quit",
                    fg="red",
                    command=quit)
butQuit.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
ButGen = tk.Button(frame,
                   text="Generate",
                   command=gen)
ButGen.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)


# Label generation
Trait1 = tk.Label(root,
                  compound=tk.CENTER,
                  text=pertrait,
                  font=fontStyle)
#                  image=paper) .pack(side="right")

Trait1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You create the Label long before `gen()` has been called.  You should probably create (or at least set the text of) the Label from within `gen()`, as that's the point at which you know what the text of the Label will be.

Comment: `print()` doesn’t return a value so `pertrait` gets set to None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print()` doesn’t return a value, and you neglected to call `gen()`!

Change:

```
pertrait = print(random.choice(open(
    'F:\\Desktop\\python\\RandomGenerator py\\CharTraitList.txt').read(
    ).split()).strip())
```

To:

```
pertrait = random.choice(open(
    'F:\\Desktop\\python\\RandomGenerator py\\CharTraitList.txt').read(
    ).split()).strip()
```

But really it would be much better t avoid the global - make `gen()` return the value and assign the result of `gen()` ot `pertrait`

Comment: `print` returns a value; it returns `None`. `gen` is called when the button is clicked. The return value of a callback isn't used, hence the global variable.

Comment: Thank you for this with your help I figured it out. Once I set gen to return instead of print it started working correctly. My next challenge is to get the label to update each time the "Generate" button is clicked. I know that the button works correctly just gotta get the next part working. Thanks for all your help!